# Hosting angular and able to view on all PC

Tags: angular

I have hosted my angular application using ng serve --host IP_Address. Since I have remotely accessed the PC from my virtual machine, I am able to ping to that machine and also I can open the virtual machine browser and open the application. However, I am not able to access the application from my Windows machine. How can I solve this?

Comment: ng serve is for local development.

Comment: Any way I can achieve the above thing?

Comment: is there a reason why you are attempting to do it this way instead of through traditional hosting means? As@robert pointed out this is not advised, if you enter `ng serve --prod` it will even warn you against doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access your development server from other machines use

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

You can also set this configuration in your `angular.json`:

```
    ...
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build",
        "host": "0.0.0.0"
    ...
```

Doing so will cause the CLI to give you the warning below to remind you that it is not a secure server.

```
WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
```

Comment: I tried this but I am still not able to view on Windows. I am not sure what problem is, as it is running properly on my Virtual Machine

Comment: In my environment I have the dev server running on Linux but I am able to view it from Windows with the configuration described. Maybe you have another networking issue.

Comment: Did you confirm that the CLI is giving you the warning shown above? If you're not getting the warning that would be an indication that it didn't take your configuration for whatever reason. If you get the warning then the dev server is set up correctly and you have another networking issue.

Comment: @FenilShah you can not connect remotely to a localhost address. `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` are not part of the network group. You have to run `ifconfig` and find the VMs IP address, and then use that as the server address. Next run `ufw status` and make sure port **4200** is allowed.